# The explanation behind the code if i'm using %s instead of %c in my printf section of the code

Tags: c++, c, printf

So i'm curious about the explanation why i'm getting different results on my code if i'm using %s on my printf section. I know the working one should use %s instead %c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char str1[12] = "Hello world!";
    printf("str1==%c\n", str1); 
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to compile it multiple times and get some different result, sometime between: str1==�, str1==, str1== (this blank space is actually some icon this site can't display)

Comment: `%c` is for a single char, `%s` is for a string AKA pointer to char. Google "undefined hevaviour C".

Comment: Why do you feel you need an explanation for what happens when you break your contract with the computer? If you tell it something is a `char` when it is not? Why expect useful/interesting/consistent/valid results with this? Why not simply use the correct code?

Answer (score 7):

`str1` decays to a `char*` in this case. With `%c` you're telling `printf` that it's a `char` which it isn't. Specifying the wrong format is undefined behavior, so there's no guarantee on what happens (it could crash the program, or do worse things even). What most likely happens is that it's trying to interpret that pointer as a `char`, which may lead to unprintable symbols.

Answer (score 5):

Here

```
printf("str1==%c\n", str1);
```

the format specifier `%c` expects argument of `char` type but provided argument `str1` is *char array* and it decays to `char*` type, compiler should have reported warning message, seems like you ignored if you could have compiled with flags like `-Wall`. Its good to compile code with below minimal flags like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic test.c
```

> warning: format specifies type `'int'` but the
>         argument has type `'char *' [-Wformat]`

Use `%s` instead of `%c`.

```
printf("str1==%s\n", str1);
```

Comment: Detail: "%c expects argument of char",is more like "the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written."

Answer (score 4):

`%c` means character, but `str1` is *not* a `char`. So you are asking `printf` to interpret `str1` as something it is not. The result you get is not well defined when you do that.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have a basic knowledge about pointer. If not please [read about it first](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/).

"str1" in your code is a pointer to char array and it points to the first element of the array ('H').

%c modifier is designed to take input a char value and print the ASCII representation of that value. In this case it is 'H'.

On the other hand, %s modifier is designed to work similar to the following way:

1. take input a pointer to char
2. make a copy of the pointer. let it be cpointer.
3. if the value of the memory location stored in the cpointer is NULL('\0') goto 7
4. print the value of the memory location stored in the cpointer.
5. increment cpointer so that it point to the next element of the char array.
6. goto 3.
7. end printing char array.

As a result, it will print the whole string. If you are wondering about how did it found '\0' in the end of the string. it can because, when we assign some value while declaring a char array (ex: char str[] = "abc") compiler automatically adds a null character in the end. For this reason, we must specify char array size to be 1 greater than the length of the string it will store. So you declaration should have been:

```
char str[13] = "Hello world!";
```

Also when we assign a value while declaring char array, we need not specify the size of the array. It is automatically determined by the comiler. So following code will work too.

```
char str[] = "Hello world!";
```

Comment: %c does not take a pointer to char, it takes an actual char, otherwise it would work and print the capital H.

Comment: my bad. fixed. thank you for noticing.

Comment: "*is a pointer to char array and it points to the first element*" is cannot be both a the same time. The latter is true, the former is false.

Comment: Also "*cpointer*" is not a common expression. You might want to name it `char`-pointer.

Comment: @Unimportant `"%c"` matches an `int`.  "the int argument is converted to an
unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."